# In Firebase when using push() How do I get the unique ID and store in my database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am pushing data in firebase, but i want to store unique id in my database also .
can somebody tell me,how to push the data with unique id.

i am trying like this

```
  writeUserData() {
    var key= ref.push().key();
    var newData={
        id: key,
        websiteName: this.webname.value,
        username: this.username.value,
        password : this.password.value,
        websiteLink : this.weblink.value
    }
    firebase.database().ref().push(newData);
  }
```

error is  "ReferenceError: ref is not defined"

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen    can you please see it

Comment: What I recall is when you call `push` it puts the unique key in the database for you, then you have to make a new child and put your data in there. I'm not sure though, I'm an Android programmer, so it might be different. And Frank won't get a notification, since if he didn't do anything on this post, he won't get notified

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can get the key by using the function `key()` of any ref object

> There are two ways to invoke `push` in Firebase's JavaScript SDK.
>
> 1. using `push(newObject)`. This will generate a new push id and write the data at the location with that id.
> 2. using `push()`. This will generate a new push id and return a reference to the location with that id. This is a *pure client-side
>      operation*.
>
> Knowing #2, you can easily get a new push id client-side with:
>
> ```
> var newKey = ref.push().key();
> ```
>
> You can then use this key in your multi-location update.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36774761/2305342

> If you invoke the Firebase `push()` method without arguments it is a
>   pure client-side operation.
>
> ```
> var newRef = ref.push(); // this does *not* call the server
> ```
>
> You can then add the `key()` of the new ref to your item:
>
> ```
> var newItem = {
>     name: 'anauleau'
>     id: newRef.key()
> };
> ```
>
> And write the item to the new location:
>
> ```
> newRef.set(newItem);
> ```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34437786/2305342

in your case :

```
writeUserData() {
  var myRef = firebase.database().ref().push();
  var key = myRef.key();

  var newData={
      id: key,
      Website_Name: this.web_name.value,
      Username: this.username.value,
      Password : this.password.value,
      website_link : this.web_link.value
   }

   myRef.push(newData);

}
```

Comment: can you please tell me by doing changing in my code.

Comment: @komaldeepsinghchahal you need to declare the ref first

Comment: can you tell me.. how... i am not getting

Comment: Is it common to store the `key` in a data object as an `id`? This is the thinking I come from, where every model has in itself, an identifier. But every Firebase example I come across never does this. Is it a bad practice?

Comment: It create another key inside key.

Comment: I had to replace ref.push().key(); with ref.push().key;
Looks like you need to get a property instead of calling a function.

Comment: If you get the error "key is not function" or "key is not defined" just delete '()' and use 'myRef.key;' only

Comment: I am looking for a solution to generate order numbers that are user friendly, form 1, 2, 3.... 1000000+. the number has to be unique and avoid race condition.

Answer (score 36):

#### [Firebase v3 Saving Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/save-data)

```
function writeNewPost(uid, username, picture, title, body) {
  // A post entry.
  var postData = {
    author: username,
    uid: uid,
    body: body,
    title: title,
    starCount: 0,
    authorPic: picture
  };

  // Get a key for a new Post.
  var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().child('posts').push().key;

  // Write the new post's data simultaneously in the posts list and the user's post list.
  var updates = {};
  updates['/posts/' + newPostKey] = postData;
  updates['/user-posts/' + uid + '/' + newPostKey] = postData;

  return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
}
```

Comment: Took me a while to realise why my code wasn't working, then I noticed the `key;` in your wonderful answer - I was using `key();`, like in v2.

Comment: how can we fetch these keys back. these are just alpha-numeric ids. How can we reference them to read back the data.

Comment: See [Getting the unique key generated by push()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#getting-the-unique-key-generated-by-push)

Comment: how is this comment not getting 100 more reputation? I spent 1 hour finding this solution!

Answer (score 6):

You can get last inserted item id using Promise like this

```
let postRef = firebase.database().ref('/post');
postRef.push({ 'name': 'Test Value' })
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res.getKey()) // this will return you ID
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Comment: Superb, it worked. Thanks but the not get Key. 

this.addressRef.push(addressObj).then(res => {
        console.log("address key = " + res.key) ;
        
      });

Comment: This should be the correct answer as .push() is different than .update(). With update the node will be deleted and created again, where with .push() you will add to the node.

Answer (score 2):

> **Try this . It worked for me**

```
this.addressRef.push(addressObj).then(res => {
    console.log("address key = " + res.key) ;
});
```

Here res.getKey() will not work but use res.key to get the latest push ID

Answer (score 0):

It looks like now .push() always returns an Observable. When applied the solutions above I had the following error: "Type 'String' has no compatible call signatures".

That being said, I refer what did work in my case for this new version:

[Type 'String' has no compatible call signatures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40453955/type-string-has-no-compatible-call-signatures)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
 var insertData = firebase.database().ref().push(newData);
 var insertedKey = insertData.getKey(); // last inserted key
```

See Here: [Saving data with firebase.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data)