# Type 'String' has no compatible call signatures

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm trying to do a [multi-path update](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html) using Firebase and AngularFire2. However, I'm getting the error above when I use this:

```
let fb = firebase.database().ref();
let key = fb.child('/path').push().key();
```

Any ideas of how I can get the key after pushing something using AngularFire2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `push` method now returns an Observable, the proper way to get the generated `$key` (using AF2) is doing the following:

```
let fb = this.af.database.list('/path');
fb.push('item').then(res => console.log(res.key));
```