# Typescript error - Expected 1 arguments, but got 0

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm getting an error with my typescript code in Ionic/Angular. The error output is:

> [22:55:09]  typescript: C:/xampp/htdocs/project x/anonymous-social/src/pages/chat/chat.ts, line: 103
>               Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.
>
> L102:  if(!this.isUserThreadEmpty) {
>
> L103:    let threadKey = this.database.list('users/'+this.userData.uid+'/threads/'+this.recipient).push().key;
>
> L104:    let recipientData = {

I don't know exactly why it's happening, I would guess that `push()` needs an argument but all the stackoverflow answers I saw online regarding how to get a `key` in firebase pointed towards this solution so I'm not sure what's going on.

The actual code is:

```
if(!this.isUserThreadEmpty) {
  let threadKey = this.database.list('users/'+this.userData.uid+'/threads/'+this.recipient).push().key;
  let recipientData = {
    recipient: this.recipient,
    threadId: threadKey,
    displayName: this.displayName,
  }
```

Any ideas? I need to pass the `key` to the `recipientData`... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `I would guess that push() needs an argument` - yes, it does ... `all the stackoverflow answers I saw online` ... can you link to one that uses `.push()` on an array like that?

Comment: @JaromandaX this one for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768576/in-firebase-when-using-push-how-do-i-get-the-unique-id-and-store-in-my-databas/38768630#38768630

Comment: @JaromandaX the official docs as well: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#getting-the-unique-key-generated-by-push

Comment: oh, so `this.database.list('users/'+this.userData.uid+'/threads/'+this.recipient)` isn't an array - sorry, my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using AngularFire2. The [`push` method in AngularFire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/src/database/interfaces.ts#L14) requires an argument.

The question and documentation you linked are for the regular Firebase JavaScript SDK, where the argument to `push` is optional.

Your best option is to do this with the regular JavaScript SDK, as there is no advantage in doing it through the AngularFire2 wrapper:

```
let threadKey = firebase.database().ref().push().key;
```

From Jane's comment: to use the Firebase JavaScript SDK you will need to:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
```

**Update (2018-06-08)**: I just found out that there's also a dedicated method [`AngularFireDatabase.createPushId()`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/src/database/database.ts#L42) that creates a push ID. So I think in your case that'd be `database.createPushId()`.

Comment: Interesting, ok. How do I load that `firebase` variable? I get `Cannot find name 'firebase'.` I'm currently only loading in `AngularFireDatabase` in my `.ts` file...

Comment: For future reference on AngularFire2  will need to import: `import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';` and then you can simply use `firebase.database().ref().push().key;` to generate a key.