# Is there a way that we can create a key in javascript to firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I already develop android app with Firebase and my concern is how to make keys in javascript to push data to firebase unlikely to android it has a generated Keys the `push()`.

I spent time with research today but it seems no luck to see one.

If you have any links that my help or suggestions, I appreciate it,Thanks.

This is the key that I mean in firebase

[image]
In android studio you can set a key using `push()`. Example in android studio `reference.child("Alvaniz_Infant_Info).push().setValue(myValue)`

Comment: You want to create it inside firestore or firebase realtime database?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768576/in-firebase-when-using-push-how-do-i-get-the-unique-id-and-store-in-my-databas

Answer (score 1):

According to the [js example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields) in firebase realtime db doc, [push()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference.html#push) is available in js sdk too.

```
  var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().child('posts').push().key;
```

Comment: That explains well, Thanks